# EF dotted navigation properties using nameof

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties, nameof

Having this model (All properties are Single (not Collection) navigation properties)

```
- University
  - Department
    - Classroom
      - Teacher
```

In order to get the dotted name for each level we have to write it manually.

```
   query.Include("Department")
        .Include("Department.Classroom")
        .Include("Department.Classroom.Teacher")
```

For the very first level we can use `nameof(University.Department)` but for the rest we have two write it manually.

How can we have it as easy as something like `nameof(University.Department.Classroom)` ?

P.S. I don't want to use `Select` or `SelectMany` extension methods, I need to have them as `string` values.

Comment: Ugly idea: `.Include(nameof(University.Department) + "." + nameof(University.Department.Classroom) + "." + nameof(University.Department.Classroom.Teacher))`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, although ugly, but if it worked it was not bad. The problem is that `nameof` doesn't work with more than one level of nesting. You will get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `

Comment: `nameof(University.Department) + "." + nameof(University.Department.Classroom) + "." + nameof(University.Department.Classroom.Teacher)` works just fine for me.

Comment: With C# 6:  
    $"{nameof(University)}.{nameof(University.Department)}"